# How do I update the text of a JTextArea inside of a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

As the question states, I'm having trouble with updating the text of a JTextArea that is inside of a JScrollPane.

I am able to grab the text from the typecasted getView() of the JScrollPane. 
However, I have tried the following to update the JTextArea.

```
((JTextArea)(chatWindow.getViewport().getView())).setText("Hello!");
```

where chatWindow is the JScrollPane.

and I have tried this:

```
chatWindowInsert.setText(processMessage());
```

where chatWindowInsert is the JTextArea in the JScrollPane

Neither work unfortunately.

I'm not getting any exceptions, or hanging.

Assistance would be appreciated!

Here is my complete code. Please excuse me vastly if I've broken a million programming practices.

```
public class ChatterBotClient extends JFrame{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static ChatterBotFactory chatterBotFactory;
private static ChatterBotSession chatterBotSession;
private static ChatterBot chatterBot;
public static JScrollPane chatWindow;
public static JTextField userInput;
public static JTextArea chatWindowInsert;
public ChatterBotClient() 
{
    try{
    chatterBotFactory = new ChatterBotFactory();
    chatterBot = chatterBotFactory.create(ChatterBotType.CLEVERBOT);
    chatterBotSession = chatterBot.createSession();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error :O");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "There has been a problem initializing the Bot. Please restart.");
    }

    initUI();
}

public void initUI()
{
    //Define the mainPanel that everything goes into in the JFrame
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    //Define the child panels of "mainPanel"
    JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel chatHistoryPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel userInputAndButtonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("ChatterBot Chat Client");
    setSize(600,300);
    setResizable(false);

    //Define each component
    //Set properties of each component
    JLabel infoLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to my Cleverbot Client! Please enjoy! :D");
        infoLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 20));
        infoLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    chatWindowInsert = new JTextArea();
        chatWindowInsert.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    chatWindow = new JScrollPane(chatWindowInsert);
        chatWindow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,225));
        chatWindow.setPreferredSize(chatWindow.getPreferredSize());


    userInput = new JTextField();
        userInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 25));

    JButton enterBtn = new JButton("Send");
        enterBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 25));

    //Add each component to the required panels
    infoPanel.add(infoLabel);

    chatHistoryPanel.add(chatWindow);

    userInputAndButtonPanel.add(userInput, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    userInputAndButtonPanel.add(enterBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //Add the child panels to the mainPanel
    mainPanel.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(chatHistoryPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(userInputAndButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //Now, add the appropriate listeners to your components
    enterBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("You clicked me! :D");
            try {
                processMessage();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Something went wrong when you pressed the button! :O");
            }
        }
    });

    userInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            chatWindow = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(processMessage()));

        }
    });

    //Tell the JFrame to display what we've made!
    add(mainPanel);     

}

public static String processMessage()
{
    try {
        String completeMessage = chatWindowInsert.getText();
        completeMessage.concat("You: " + userInput.getText() + "\n");
        String response = chatterBotSession.think(userInput.getText());
        completeMessage.concat("Bot: " + response + "\n");
        userInput.setText("");
        return completeMessage;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ChatterBotClient cli = new ChatterBotClient();
            cli.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean "having trouble with updating the text" and " that still doesn't work"? Any exceptions? Hanging? missing text?

Comment: My apologies. I have edited the question so it should be a lot more clearer! I'm running on very little sleep!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state:

> As the question states, I'm having trouble with updating the text of a JTextArea that is inside of a JScrollPane.
>
> I am able to grab the text from the typecasted getView() of the JScrollPane. However, I have tried the following to update the JTextArea.

```
((JTextArea)(chatWindow.getViewport().getView())).setText("Hello!");
```

---

---

Why go through all of this fragile code gymnastics? Much simpler, safer and easier would be to create a class level JTextArea instance field that is then displayed in your GUI in a JScrollPane, and simply obtain text or set text on that instance. No muss, no fuss, no bugs.

If this cannot be done with your current program, then you've not yet told us enough that would suggest otherwise, and you will need to tell us much more.

---

**Edit**
Replies to your comments:

> have variables referencing both the JTextArea and the JTextField (just to try and figure this out) but even if I change either variable using one of the appropriate ways I described above, the contents inside of the JTextArea still won't change. Unless I'm not understanding what you're saying?

Then this suggests that while you might be working the correct variable, perhaps you're working on the wrong reference. Perhaps the variables you're working with are not held in the GUI that is currently displayed.

But this is all nothing but SWAG-work (silly wild-ass guess-work). Please don't force us to guess -- edit your original post and show us your code, best an [sscce](http://sscce.org), show us how you're getting your handle to these variables and how you know that they belong to the **displayed** gui.

---

**Edit 2**
Regarding your latest code. Let's look at this line:

```
public static JTextArea chatWindowInsert;
```

1. This field should not be static, and of this I am 100% certain.
2. Where do you add any object that this field eventually refers to, to your GUI? I can't find this anywhere in your posted code.

---

**Edit 3**

I see now that you put a completely different JTextField into a JScrollPane, never put it into the GUI anywhere, and do all of this on button push of all places!?

```
userInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        chatWindow = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(processMessage()));

    }
});
```

Suggestions:

1. Don't do this.
2. Don't create a new JTextArea and new JScrollPane every time that this action listener is activated
3. Don't create components and just leave them hanging out to rot, not placing key components in the GUI.
4. Instead put your JTextArea int the GUI when you construct the GUI. Once and once only.

Comment: I have variables referencing both the JTextArea and the JTextField (just to try and figure this out) but even if I change either variable using one of the appropriate ways I described above, the contents inside of the JTextArea still won't change. Unless I'm not understanding what you're saying?

Comment: @Pilapodapostache: more *unusual* code. See edit 3. YOu may want to re-start this program from the ground up.

Comment: Well darn. I guess I got some more learning to do! Thank you for the help. I'll mark it as the answer (you've answered my question afaic)